# extra field in many to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc application using hibernate, I have a `ManyToMany` relationship between a `Patient` entity and an `Organization` entity.  This relationship is managed by a junction table called `organizationpatientjunction` which contains a link to the integer `id` of `Patient` and the String `root` of `Organization`.  The problem is that each `organization` has its own unique id for the `patient` and I want to be able to save, store, and retrieve each of the unique ids for the `patient`/`organization` combinations.  How can I re-write my code below so that I can retrieve the `orgpatientid` for a given `organization`/`patient` combination?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="organizationpatientjunction",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="patient_id")},
        //do I add something here for the other organization's own patient id?
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="org_id")})
    private Set<Organization> providerorganizations = new HashSet<Organization>();

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @Column(name="root")
    private String root;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="providerorganizations")
    private Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<Patient>();

    //getters and setters
}

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patient(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  #other fields
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS organization(
  root varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(200)
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS organizationpatientjunction(
  patient_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  org_root varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  # Do I add orgpatientid varchar(100) here to store the other organization's patient id?
  FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES patient(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (org_root) REFERENCES organization(root)
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your object model you should change the Set<Organization> to Map<Organization, ...>.

Now you have two options:

1. Use value objects (embeddable in JPA) as value type of your map -e.g. String.
2. Use an entity as value type.

This javadoc describes both options as example 2 and 3: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html

In your code, you also have the reverse association (inverse mapping) from Organization to Person. It's this required? I suggest to remove it, although it its possible. You should however also change it to Map<..., Person> and map it accordingly.

`@ElementCollection @CollectionTable(name="organizationpatientjunction", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="patient_id")}) 
@Column(name="patient_number")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="org_root")
private Map<Organization,String> providerorganizations = ...`

public String getPatientNumberFor(Organization o) {
  return providerorganizations.get(o);
}

You should remove the reverse mapping (remove the Set<Person>) for now and later try to map it correctly.

Comment: Thank you.  I read your link but I am still confused.  I have spent all day tinkering with this problem from multiple standpoints, but I am not any closer to fixing it.  Can you please show me explicit code that will fix this problem? I think that is the only way that I can understand this.

Comment: In addition to not knowing how to set up the relationships in the entity definition, I also do not understand how to set up the getters and setters.  The documentation you sent was not clear.

Comment: I'm writing this on my mobile, so it's difficult to write correct code and impossible to test. I'll do what I can.

Comment: Thank you.  I just really do not understand, and this is causing me a bottleneck.  Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think I want example 3 in the javadoc (using entities as value types), but it does not show the DDL for the database tables, and it also does not show the getters and setters.  Plus, I am not sure how to translate it all to my Patient and Organization entities in my original posting above.  In the end I would want to be able to save,store, and retrieve the orgpatientid value from whatever junction table stores the relationship between Patient and Organization.

Comment: @CodeMed I've added an example according to example 2 in javadoc. I think this is the simplest approach. The DB schema can stay as-is, with a column patient_number in the organization_patient table for the added property.

Comment: @CodeMed That should do it, I think.